# Problems running C++ program as cronjob

Tags: php, c++, linux, bash, cron

I'm having problems with a C++ program which I try to run as a cronjob, and I've been trying all kinds of things, next to looking for a solution online for an entire day.

The program runs perfectly when run from the commandprompt and it does run as a cronjob, but it has some problems with executing other scripts that are run from within the program.

I think it has something to do with the fact that bash and php cant be found, because I am getting the following errors:

> /usr/bin/bash: ./hpDownloadFeed.sh: No such file or directory
>
> Could not open input file: mailDifference.php

These files are called within a C++ program that is run as a cronjob, which is called as:

> * */1 * * * /absolute/path/to/file

the calls to the files within the C++ file are as follows:

```
system("/usr/bin/bash -c ./hpDownloadFeed.sh");

string phpCommand = "/usr/bin/php -f mailDifference.php " + sizeDifference + ' ' + sizeTotal + ' ' + negative ;
    std::system(phpCommand.c_str());
```

when I do which php/bash I get:

> /usr/bin/bash and /usr/bin/php

And I also added the following to the top of the crontab at the advice of someone online.

> ATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Also at the top of the bash/php files I put

> #!/usr/bin/php
>
> #!/usr/bin/bash

I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance,

Anti

Comment: Does is make any difference if you use absolute path to hpDownloadFeed.sh and mailDifference.php?

Comment: You try to run the script from the current working directory. Did you implement a `chdir` command to the correct directory? Or, put in other words: What is the working directory of your program? I assume it's the home directory of the user.

Comment: Generally, using `system` a lot in C++ to run `php` or `bash` is a bad idea. Consider using libraries (e.g. [vmime](http://www.vmime.org/) to send emails, [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to download). This is faster and more secure (less dependencies on external programs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the absolute path to `mailDifference.php` and `hpDownloadFeed.sh` within the C++ program.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the PHP problem. But 
**system("/usr/bin/bash -c ./home/hollandPharmaCompare/bin/hpDownloadFeed.sh");**

still gives me the same error:

**/usr/bin/bash: ./home/hollandPharmaCompare/bin/hpDownloadFeed.sh: No such file or directory**

Comment: @AntiFTW Absolute paths don't start with ".".

Comment: removed the . at the start and now it seems to work, let me recheck and I will mark your response as an answer.

Comment: So stupid, I'm sure I did try absolute paths at some point yesterday, but I was trying out all kinds of stuff so I think I must have broke it someother way before. Thanks for the quick response. it's working now :)